# OpenCL chips: which to pick for GPGPU, how to have both AMD & nVidia in one machine

Tags: opencl, gpu, nvidia, amd-processor

I will be developing GPGPU simulations using OpenCL (doble-precision). I would like to have both nVidia and AMD chips in my new workstation, for testing.

1. Is such configuration (both AMD and nVidia) supported under Linux? I assume I have to use proprietary drivers for both to get decent performance, and I am not sure if they will not clash somehow?
2. Is it possible to use one of the cards to drive graphics displays, while it will be also available for OpenCL code? (I assume so, but better to be sure)
3. What hardware would you recommend? I don't need extremely expensive one (Tesla is beyond my budget), but it must support double-precision. I found nVidia's GTX560 could be fine, not too expensive, while still featureful. Is it a good choice?
4. For AMD hw, should I go for gamer-oriented Radeon HD 6970 (according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Northern_Islands_.28HD_6xxx.29_series), only >= HD6950 support double-precision FP), or for the FirePro line -- FV5900 or FV7900?

Comment: I'm not sure about dual-vendor Linux solutions -- I've only ever used a single vendor under Linux.  I do know that Apple's CL stack supports AMD and NVIDIA simultaneously, and permits sharing between OpenCL and OpenGL regardless of which card is doing which work.  Meaning, you can render the contents of a VBO using OpenGL on the AMD card that you have populated via OpenCL using the NVIDIA card.

Comment: Regarding AMD: You could also buy older HD 5850/5870. Their DP performance is nearly the same as of HD6970, but they are cheaper (you can get used one from ebay for less than 100$). Professional GPUs, AFAIK, have no advantage over mainstream ones, but are more expensive: they use the same chip, so the only differences are memory amount/speed/type (which is often the only reason to buy Tesla instead of GeForce, but looks like not of big importance for you) and clocks (and CPU and RAM frequencies of pro GPUs are usually lower to improve stability)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use such configuration.

1. Yes. If you have multiple GPUs you can use each vendor for each. But you have to register your device. Read the installation notes for Linux sytems. You can also run Intel or even AMD on you CPU (Assuming you have Multi-core CPU). You even can use AMD's OpenCL for some Intel processors (It seems to work, but no guarantee there). 
   You might see some devices (CPU probably) listed twice if you have Intel and AMD OpenCL on the same machine.
2. Yes.
3. If I am not mistaken starting from GTX260 NVIDIA cards have double-precision support. You can use a cheaper one for development and move to a better GPU for testing or measurement.
4. Maybe someone else can help you with that. I don't have much info about AMD GPUs.